# Arithmetic sequence and a rectangular triangle

Tags: arithmetic

Task:
Calculate the smallest angle in a rectangular (or right) triangle whose sides form an arithmetic sequence.

That's it.. and I can't solve it. The solution is 36°52'.

p.s.: thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can set the sides to be $a-d,a,a+d$

So we have $(a-d)^2+a^2=(a+d)^2\iff a^2=4ad\iff a=4d$ as $a>0$

So, the sides become $3d,4d,5d$

The smallest angle is due to the smallest side

So, if $A$ is the smallest angle $\displaystyle\sin A=\frac{3d}{5d}=\frac35$

Comment: wow thank you soo much!! You're fast! :)

Comment: @Anja97, my pleasure. Hope I could make the idea clear

Comment: Yes, you sure did :) It's exactly what I was looking for :) thank you again!

Comment: I find it interesting that this shows that the 3-4-5 right triangle is the *only* one (aside from scaling) with sides in an arithmetic sequence.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're looking at a right triangle with integer side lengths.  The side lengths for these triangles are called [Pythagorean triples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triples).  Look at the site I linked to.  Which Pythagorean triple has small values and is an arithmetic sequence?  (The angle is more accurately approximately $36^\circ52'11.63''$.)